# .Net 7 file logger, one file per service instance

Tags: c#, .net, logging

Hello I'm trying to make my .NET 7 app to log into different files based on service instance.

I would like to use default .NET logging. But I'm open to suggestions for third party libraries.

I've written custom file logger provider.

```
    [ProviderAlias("FileLogger")]
    public class FileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private readonly FileLoggerOptions _options;

        public FileLoggerProvider(IOptions<FileLoggerOptions> options)
        {
            _options = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

            if(!Directory.Exists(_options.FolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_options.FolderPath);
            }
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new FileLogger(Path.Combine(_options.FolderPath, _options.FileName));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

And I differentiate to which file to write based on EventId

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
{
    if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
    {
        return;
    }

    var formattedFilePath = _filePath
        .Replace("{eventName}", eventId.Name ?? "Program")
        .Replace("{date}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

    var logRecord = string.Format("{0} [{1}] {2} {3}", "[" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+00:00") + "]", logLevel.ToString(), formatter(state, exception), exception != null ? exception.StackTrace : "");
    
    using var fileStream = new FileStream(formattedFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

    streamWriter.WriteLine(logRecord);
}
```

Called like so:

```
public SynchronizationWorker(ILogger<SynchronizationWorker> logger, SynchronizationItemOptions options)
{
    _logger = logger;

    _loggerEventId = new EventId((int)options.Region, options.Region.ToString());
    _logger.LogInformation(_loggerEventId, "Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
}
```

And I register my services like so:

```
foreach (var itemOption in options.Items)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SynchronizationWorker>(serviceProvider => {
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<SynchronizationWorker>>();
        return new SynchronizationWorker(logger, itemOption);
    });
}
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't the best way to do it, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Is there a better way to do it ?